# Separating number from string

Tags: vba, excel, split

Is any simple way to separate second number from this string (number can have too digit):

```
variable = Test +5 test (1e8+2) 'in this case 1
```

and assign it to variable2? I tried this code:

```
temporary = split(variable)

variable2 = temporary(4) 'Now i don't know how to separate i from "(" and "e"
```

Comment: I assume `Test +5 test (1e8+2)` is a string given your use of split.  Will `variable2 = Mid(temporary(4), 2, 1)` meet your requirement?  If not, you need to clarify your question.

Comment: @TonyDallimore In this case variable2 must contain 1.

Comment: I did not check your code.  It should be `temporary(3)` not `temporary(4)`.  `Mid(temporary(3), 2, 1)` extracts the second character of `temporary(3)` which is "1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using regular expressions to return the 2nd digit (or sequential digits) in a string:

```
Dim variable As String
Dim variable2 As Long
Dim RE As Object
variable = "Test +5 test (1e8+2)" 'in this case 1

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Pattern = "\D*\d\D*(\d+).*"
    variable2 = .Replace(variable, "$1")
End With
```

If the **first** number can also be more than one digit, change the first **\d** to **\d+**