# Regular expression - separating numbers

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I want to separate numbers from string and assign them to new variables. The strings is like that:

```
Test +5 anything (1e8+2) 
Test2 test1 +4 anything2 (1e8+3/×3)
```

I use this function:

```
Function REGULAR(ByVal WhichString As String, _
                        ByVal Pattern As String, _
                        ByVal ReplaceWith As String, _
                        Optional ByVal IsGlobal As Boolean = True, _
                        Optional ByVal IsCaseSensitive As Boolean = True) As String
'Declaring the object
Dim objRegExp As Object
'Initializing an Instance
Set objRegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
'Setting the Properties
objRegExp.Global = IsGlobal
objRegExp.Pattern = Pattern
objRegExp.IgnoreCase = Not IsCaseSensitive
'Execute the Replace Method
RegExpReplace = objRegExp.Replace(WhichString, ReplaceWith)

End Function
```

Firstly I tried to assign 1 (from first string) to variable:

```
variable1 = Split(string)

variable = REGULAR(variable1(3), "\d", vbNullString, True)
```

but the variable is empty. What is did wrong (I found this function on internet)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Separating number from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23461903/separating-number-from-string)

Comment: @simoco Now I ask about this specific function. It's easier for me to use function then script. So maybe anyone can show me how to separete this number?

Comment: It is unclear what you expect the output to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a string consisting of numbers and other characters and only want the numbers, try:

```
Public Function NumPart(Inn) As Long
    temp = ""
    For i = 1 To Len(Inn)
        ch = Mid(Inn, i, 1)
        If ch Like "[0-9]" Then temp = temp & ch
    Next i
    NumPart = CLng(temp)
End Function
```

Comment: wont handle `1e8` if this is the string to extract.